# Any way to pipe System Console output back to a window inside Blender?

Tags: python

I know the system console needs to be a separate window. However if there was a way to pipe that output to a window within Blender that would be great.

This is purely a workflow question, but I'm constantly having to switch back and forth to the console window to check things. So instead of seeing this in the output console:

```
Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

Couldn't that window be used to display everything instead (assuming it could be toggled for folks who don't want see everything)?

Comment: When scripts fail they can produce a lot of error messages. Personally I find the system console easier to deal with when this happens, but I do understand your frustration while developing, knowing the errors will be short. You could run Blender from another process and capture everything going to the system console, but then you have to do something with it.

Comment: Ideally I could pipe everything from system console into the Info window. Since it's already in the scripting layout then would be quite handy to get results and feedback in the same layout. There may be a way to redirect all STDERR and STDOUT from inside python itself by introducing in a debug mode. It's been a while since I've done that so will have to research a bit.